# C programming: casting a void pointer to an int?

Tags: c, pointers, void

Say I have a void* named ptr. How exactly should I go about using ptr to store an int?  Is it enough to write

```
ptr = (void *)5;
```

If I want to save the number 5? Or do I have to malloc something to save it?

Comment: Yes, what you have there will work just fine. Whether it's a good idea or not depends on what exactly you're trying to do, but there's no problem with that code as it is.

Comment: The `cast` is sufficient..................

Comment: Why, for the goodness sake, do you want to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do? We need to see the bigger picture to help you. Now I can only guess that the code you posted is probably not doing what you would expect it to do.

Comment: Do you want a pointer to memory location 5 or to the number 5? There is a big difference between the two.

Comment: We do this for passing undefined data to callback functions

Answer (score 49):

You're casting `5` to be a void *pointer* and assigning it to `ptr`.

Now **ptr points at the memory address 0x5**

If that actually is what you're trying to do .. well, yeah, that works. You ... probably don't want to do that.

When you say "store an int" I'm going to guess you mean you want to actually store the integer value 5 in the memory pointed to by the `void*`. As long as there was enough memory allocated ( `sizeof(int)` ) you could do so with casting ...

```
void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*((int*)ptr) = 5;

printf("%d\n",*((int*)ptr));
```

Comment: I do this all the time, when working with a framework that stores "User Data" as a `void*`, but all I need is an int.

Comment: As long as someone after you doesn't accidentally dereference it later, I agree that works. It just makes me cringe a bit for that reason.

Comment: And I knew there was something else that was bugging me - it's not portable. http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah! That's exactly what I was running into. So it's a proper use case. Thanks.

Comment: If the OP had to ask whether to use a malloc or not, it means that he needs to use a malloc.  One does not simply walk into storing ints in pointer spaces.

Answer (score 7):

That will work on all platforms/environments where `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(int)`, which is probably most of them, but I think not all of them. You're not supposed to rely on it.

If you can you should use a union instead:

```
union {
    void *ptr;
    int i;
};
```

Then you can be sure there's space to fit either type of data and you don't need a cast. (Just don't try to dereference the pointer while its got non-pointer data in it.)

Alternatively, if the reason you're doing this is that you were using an int to store an address, you should instead use <strike>`size_t`</strike> **`intptr_t`** so that that's big enough to hold any pointer value on any platform.

Comment: No, don't use `size_t`. It isn't guaranteed to be able to hold all possible addresses of pointers. `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are there for that since C99. In C90 you're out of luck. I can even give you a platform where `size_t` is 16 bits wide and pointers are 32 bits wide: x86 in real mode using memory model `HUGE`, `FAR` and `COMPACT`. `size_t` can be seen as the type used for addressing arrays, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer always points to a memory address. So if you want to save a variable with pointer, what you wanna save in that pointer is the memory address of your variable.