# Trying to pass integer argument to thread

Tags: c, multithreading

Hi I am having trouble passing an integer argument to a thread and calculation the factorial using that integer. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void * factorial(void * number) {

    int factorial = 1;
    int counter = 1;

    int newnum = *((int*)number);
    printf("%d", newnum);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * sumup( void * number) {


}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc != 2) {
            printf("Argument number error\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
            printf(argv[i]);
            printf("\n");
    }

    int rc;
    void * t = argv[1];
    rc = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, factorial, (void*)t );
    if (rc != 0) {
            printf("There was an error creating the thread\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    exit(0);

}
```

Right now i am just trying to print the integer sent to get it working properly but here is my output:

./Task1
5
1162608693

It should printing out 5 instead of 1162608693

Comment: 1162608693 decinal is 0x454C0035 - note the last byte - 0x35, or ASCII '5'.

Comment: You may be trying to pass an integer argument, but you are not.  You are passing a pointer to a char array,

Comment: How would i get it to pass the int? I tried using void * t = atoi(argv[1]); but this gave me an error

Comment: malloc space for sizeof(int),  Load it up with atoi().  Pass the pointer. Dereference it in the thread. free() the pointer at the end of the thread function, just before it returns.

Comment: Ok, now i have void * t = malloc(sizeof(int)); followed by t = atoi(argv[1]); but i am still getting that im trying to make a point from integer without a cast

Comment: 't* = atoi(argv[1])'

Comment: @09nduffey It sounds like you don't know how pointers work.  I doubt that SE is the best way to learn about pointers, you would be better off looking up a tutorial or textbook on programming in C.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7828480/2572431 for an example of how to store an `int` on the heap.

Comment: @MartinJames This worked. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @augurar I will check out a tutorial or two to see if i can refresh myself on how they work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`argv` table stores pointers to characters. By doing:

```
void * t = argv[1];
int newnum = *((int*) t );
```

what you are trying to print is integer value of string `"5"`. You are passing address of string:

```
'5' '\0'
```

casted to pointer to `int`, therefore you try to read integer value of first `sizeof(int)` bytes which yields:

```
5 0 [and you read sizeof(int)-2 bytes out of range]
```

which results in undefined behavior.

SOLUTION

To convert to integer a string passed as argument to your program use `atoi` or `strtol` which does better error checking.